# On Linux mongo can't normal boot

Tags: linux, mongodb

I have triggered actions:

1. Mandatory kill a mongo
2. The modified configuration file
3. Delete a mongo - 27017.

//service mongod status ⬇️

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2L01.png)

The sockBelow is the latest log, don't know have no rain 
 //var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

**Please don't pay attention to date , Because I didn't change**

```
2017-09-09T08:07:06.059+0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten]          building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2017-09-09T08:07:06.068+0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
2017-09-09T08:07:06.068+0800 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.4
2017-09-09T08:07:06.074+0800 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-09-09T09:44:31.906+0800 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2017-09-09T09:44:31.906+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-09-09T09:44:31.906+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2017-09-09T09:44:31.906+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 8
2017-09-09T09:44:31.906+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-09-09T09:44:31.907+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-09-09T09:44:31.907+0800 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2017-09-09T09:44:31.911+0800 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2017-09-09T09:44:32.040+0800 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2017-09-09T09:44:32.040+0800 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2017-09-09T09:44:32.040+0800 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
2017-09-09T09:44:32.143+0800 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
```

Comment: The younger brother for the first time in the overflow questions, give a face

Comment: Can you check your mongod config file for syntax errors and paste here?